# How to implement MSMQ Receive as like Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, msmq

We are migrating application from Azure to On Prem which has Queue option and decided to implement MSMQ as like Azure Queue but some of the options are not exactly available in MSMQ queue.

1. AddMessage & Peekmessage in Azure Queue and Send & Peek in MSMQ are Same
2. GetMessage in Azure Queue is used to get the next queue message and we can set the visibility time to avoid others to process the same queue.
   Receive in MSMQ to get the latest message and at the same time it automatically deleted from the queue.
3. DeleteMessage in Azure Queue, everything is fine after fetching the message from queue then we have to delete the message using DeletMessage but we don't have this option available in MSMQ.
4. Updatemessage in Azure Queue is used to update the message but we dont have this option in MSMQ.

Please help me, How to implement the GetMessage as like we are using in Azure Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's an easy way to do that.

To delete and get message, you just need to dequeue it and proccess it.

You can do that using method ReceiveById:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t877y0k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thx @Thiago. yes I can use Peek and ReceiveById for that but how to lock the message when we use Peek since same message should not be processed again by others as like Getmessage with visibility time in Azure Queue.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an option. But why should you use peek instead of receive?

Comment: So many users simultaneously access the queue in our application. In that, We should not allow the users to access the same queue since lot of functionality depends on queue after the process. This is the main issue.